# Select Columns based on value of another variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Suppose I have this code:

```
DECLARE @IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs tinyint

-- Value of @IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs set here ! --

IF(@IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs = 1)
     SELECT AddressIds FROM RTS.ADDRESSES
ELSE
     SELECT DISTINCT(AddressIds) FROM RTS.ADDRESSES
```

Can I combine the two `SELECT` statements into one ? That is, using just one `SELECT`, I show either all AddressIDs, or just one of each ?

Comment: Why you want to archieve by doing it? It will execute only one select in your case

Comment: Yeah I know that .. Its just for my own curiosity :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT AddressIds FROM RTS.ADDRESSES WHERE @IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT(AddressIds) FROM RTS.ADDRESSES WHERE @IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs <> 1
```

Since the `WHERE` clauses are mutually exclusive, only one of the `UNION`-ed queries would return some rows; the other query will return nothing.

Comment: hmm ... Interesting, but that is still two outer SELECTs in a way .. Isn't there a way so that there is only one outer SELECT ? If no better solutions come, I'll mark this as the answer ..

Comment: @Ahmad The fact that there are two `SELECT`s in the statement does not make the RDBMS to select anything twice: the optimizer of any RDBMS will see that a condition is `false` all the time, and produce an empty result without touching the table. Your program makes a single round-trip to the database, too, so the performance is not going to suffer either.

Answer (score 1):

If the table contains a unique column then you can use this option (assuming the unique column's name to be `Id`):

```
DECLARE @IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs tinyint = 1
SELECT AddressIds
FROM RTS.ADDRESSES
GROUP BY CASE WHEN @IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs = 1 
              THEN Id ELSE AddressIds END, AddressIds
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8f3eb/6)

Comment: This is basically what I had in mind too. Alternatively, if `Id` is numeric, you could simply `GROUP BY @IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs * Id, AddressIds` (assuming the parameter only takes the value of either `0` or `1`).

Comment: Agreed, it was smart solution. What can you say about this solution:GROUP BY (@IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs * AddressIds) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), AddressIds.It is safe or not? @Andriy M

Comment: Er, not sure, sorry. Some aspects of SQL are not my strongest side, to be honest. What exactly do you mean by "safe", anyway?

Comment: Is it possible that the expression (@IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs * AddressIds) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) does not return a unique value when @IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs=1?

Comment: Oh, I see. As I understand it, `RAND()` is about *randomness*, not *uniqueness*. Even though [the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx "RAND (Transact-SQL)") says that *‘Repetitive calls of RAND() with the same seed value return the same results’*, it doesn't follow that repetitive calls with *different* seeds necessarily produce different output values. So yes, in my estimation, it should be possible for that expression to return non-unique values.

Comment: Ok. And what do you think about this option (@IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs * AddressIds) * CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) AS int) when @IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs=1?

Comment: Are you trying to find a universal way of generating unique integer values? With CHECKSUM, that method can't be totally reliable. The [CHECKSUM manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) says: `If one of the values in the expression list changes, the checksum of the list also generally changes. However, there is a small chance that the checksum will not change`. Perhaps, multiplying the result by AddressIds reduces the chance of a duplicate, but I wouldn't say it eliminates it completely. Besides, multiplying a random integer by an integer may result in arithmetic overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could include the number of duplicate addresses.

```
SELECT AddressIDs, count(*) as cnt
FROM RTS.ADDRESSES
GROUP BY AdressIDs
```

Comment: I don't want a count. I just want the extra duplicate AddressIDs to not show ... Only one of each should show ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) dynamic sql to form your query as a string (and set as many columns as you want) and then execute it:

```
DECLARE @IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs tinyint
DECLARE @Columns varchar(500);  

IF(@IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs = 1) SET @Columns='AddressIds'
ELSE SET @Columns='DISTINCT(AddressIds)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql N'SELECT ' + @Columns +  'AddressIds FROM RTS.ADDRESSES';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs TINYINT 
SELECT @IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs = 0

SELECT t.AddressIds
FROM (
    SELECT 
          AddressIds
        , cnt = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AddressIds ORDER BY AddressIds)
    FROM RTS.ADDRESSES
) t
WHERE @IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs = 1
    OR (@IncludeDuplicateAddressIDs != 1 AND cnt = 1)
```

In this query, the UNION or DISTINCT construction is not used. Therefore, SQL can generate a more efficient query plan.